# Passing a pointer to an array to a function

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to modify elements of an array in a function. This works fine when kept in main but when I port it to a function it segfaults after accessing the first member of the array.

The code below is just a reduced version of my actual code to show where I'm getting the segfault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned short id;
} voter;

void initialise(voter** votersPtr, unsigned short *numOfVoters) {
    *votersPtr = malloc(sizeof(voter)*(*numOfVoters));

    for(int i = 0; i < *numOfVoters; i++) {
        votersPtr[i]->id = (unsigned short) i;
        printf("%hu \n", votersPtr[i]->id);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned short numOfVoters = 480;
    voter* voters = NULL;

    initialise(&voters, &numOfVoters);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: One way to avoid this sort of error is to make the `initialise` function start with `voter *ptr = malloc...`, and then at the end, do `*votersPtr = ptr;` . IMHO this makes the code easier to read, and also means that if you have to abort the function for some reason part-way through constructing the result, you don't end up with the caller seeing partially-constructed result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type `voter **` is ambiguously either a *pointer to an array of pointers to `voter` objects* or a *pointer to a pointer to an array of `voter` objects*.  Your code is using it as the first, but should be using it as the second.  Change

```
votersPtr[i]->id = ...
```

to

```
(*votersPtr)[i].id = ...
```

and everything should work.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation as to why I can't use "->", I understand the issue now.

Answer (score 2):

`votersPtr[i]->id`, which is the same as `(*votersPtr[i]).id` should be `(*votersPtr)[i].id`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `votersPtr` is a pointer to a pointer of an array.

So shouldn't the following line:

```
votersPtr[i]->id = (unsigned short) i;
```

Instead be:

```
(*votersPtr)[i].id = (unsigned short) i;
```

Comment: Thank you! I had actually tried this and forgot to change it in the printf statement causing the segfault to still occur.